# Concise, idiomatic way to filter an array and break references?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

Today I've learned that `array_filter` preserves references in arrays:

```php
$str = 'original';
$refArray = [&$str];
$filtered = array_filter($refArray, fn () => true);
$filtered[0] = 'MODIFIED';
echo $str;  // prints MODIFIED
```

<sup>([3v4l](https://3v4l.org/oR8c6))</sup>

I'm looking for a clean, concise, idiomatic way to filter an array producing a result that is safe for modification, ie. `echo $str` would print `original`.

Looping over the array seems to work: `$value` assignment drops the reference. It's not concise though (6 lines vs. 1) and a comment is necessary to explain why this approach is used:

```php
$filtered = [];
foreach ($refArray as $key => $value) {
    if (true /*your filter here*/) {
        $filtered[$key] = $value;
    }
}
$filtered[0] = 'MODIFIED';
echo $str;  // prints original
```

I've tried to copy the input array with `array_combine`, but apparently it preserves references too, along with `array_values`:

```php
$copy = array_combine(array_keys($refArray), array_values($refArray));
$filtered = array_filter($copy, fn () => true);
$filtered[0] = 'MODIFIED';
echo $str;  // prints MODIFIED
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an array of references, as a work around you might use array_map (which will return the same amount of items)

Reading [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

> Iterates over each value in the array passing them to the callback
> function. If the callback function returns true, the current value
> from array is returned into the result array.

Reading [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

> returns an array containing the results of applying the callback to
> the corresponding index of array

When testing this (on PHP 7.4.3), it seems that when using array_filter and the callback returns true, the current value (the reference) is returned. For array_map, the reference is used in then callback and returns the value that it references.

For example

```
$str = 'original';
$refArray = [&$str];
$refArray[0] = 'MODIFIED';
echo $str;  // prints MODIFIED

$str2 = 'original2';
$refArray2 = [&$str2];
$refArray2 = array_filter($refArray2, fn() => true);
$refArray2[0] = 'MODIFIED';
echo $str2;  // prints MODIFIED

$str3 = 'original3';
$refArray3 = [&$str3];
$refArray3 = array_map(fn($x) => $x, $refArray3);
$refArray3[0] = 'MODIFIED';
echo $str3;  // prints original3

$str4 = ['original4'];
$refArray4 = [&$str4];
$refArray4 = array_map(fn($x) => $x, $refArray4);
$refArray4[0][0] = 'MODIFIED';
var_dump($str4);  
// gives
//array(1) {
//  [0]=>
//  string(9) "original4"
//}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$refArray` is array of references, not values thus `array_filter` returns same elements you passed in - references.

IMO this is wrong assumption from the very beggining, but don't know your context.

The only solution you have is to create new array with values based on array of refs.

You can achieve this with looping as you did or just flipping array twice, because array key cannot be reference. But

- it works only on primitives
- it works only if you have unique values in the array

example:

```
$str = 'original';
$refArray = [&$str];
$filtered = array_filter(array_flip(array_flip($refArray)), fn () => true);
$filtered[0] = 'MODIFIED';
echo $str;  // prints original
```

**I wouldn't call it solution but rather dirty workaround.**

Answer (score 0):

`lstrojny/functional-php`'s  [`select()`](https://github.com/lstrojny/functional-php/blob/main/docs/functional-php.md#reject--select) or its alias `filter()` should do the job because it's [using a loop](https://github.com/lstrojny/functional-php/blob/main/src/Functional/Select.php) internally.

It's a drop-in replacement for `array_filter`:

```php
use function Functional\filter;
$filtered = filter($refArray, fn () => true);
```

Serialization also removes the reference, although it will be more resource-heavy and can have additional side effects if magic methods are implemented for array values:

```php
$copy = unserialize(serialize($refArray));
$filtered = array_filter($copy, fn () => true);
```

Comment: You wrote `filter`, but the function you linked to is called `select`. Might be worth mentioning in the answer itself that this is an alias, especially since linked resources can be broken in the future. Also, how is an external package a "concise" way? It is no different than writing your own extension, which is more than the 6 lines you presented in the question as something undesirable.

Comment: @El_Vanja Thanks, edited. I can see that pulling in an additional dependency just to solve this issue may be an overkill. Still, it gets the job done, you don't have to maintain it and it's a useful library overall (IMO) so I've posted it as one way to solve this. I'm open to other solutions though.